# how to get first K smallest number in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

For example, I have a dictionary

```
dicts["A"] = 1
dicts["B"] = 2
dicts["C"] = 3 # .....etc,
```

if I want to get the first 2 key, i.e.`"A"` and `"B"` based on their values, i.e. 1 and 2, what should I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Choose another data structure because iterating the values of a dict to find something is not what they are build for. have a look at `dict.items()` and `dict.values()` functions of the dict

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get key by value in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary)

Comment: You may want to take a look at ``collections.Counter`` instead of a plain ``dict``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dic={'A':1,'B':2, 'C': 3}
k = 2
[y[0] for y in sorted(dic.items(), key = lambda x: x[1])[:k]]
```

The last line sort the dictionary items according to the key (`x[1]`), then take the first `k` items (`[:k]`) and then extract only the keys (`y[0]`).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#lets say
dic={'A':2,'B':1, 'C':5}
#sorting the dict
dic = {k: v for k, v in sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}
```

Now that the dictionary is sorted, iterate through it.
To find K smallest Values:

```
k = K
for i in range(k):
    print([k[0] for k in dic.items()][i])
```

Therefore, shortly:

```
k = K
for i in range(k):
    print([k[0] for k in {k: v for k, v in sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}.items()][i])
```

As a One-Liner:

```
k = K
dic={'A':2,'B':1, 'C':5}
print('\n'.join([k[0] for k in {k: v for k, v in sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}.items()][i] for i in range(k)))
```