# Dictionary values search

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a JSON file which I have converted into a dictionary 
using the code below:

```py
Newdict=r.json()
```

`r` has the same data which `newdict` has.

```py
Newdict= {'name':'jas','surname':'kumar','age':19,'country':'IN'}
{'name':'arch','surname':'sahu','age':29,'country':'Sl'}
{'name':'salman','surname':'khan','age':20,'country':'pk'}
{'name':'raju','surname':'reddy','age':32,'country':'usa'}
```

I want search for something like `age = 20` then print `salman`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post any example code of your attempts?

Comment: I have tried  the below code of leo and its worked  for me

Comment: Check out the most upvoted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8023337/503835. Apply the loop to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
Newdict= [{'name':'jas','surname':'kumar','age':'19','country':'IN'},
{'name':'arch','surname':'sahu','age':'29','country':'Sl'},
{'name':'salman','surname':'khan','age':'20','country':'pk'},
{'name':'raju','surname':'reddy','age':'32','country':'usa'}]

for i in Newdict:
    if int(i['age']) == 20:
        print(i['name'])
```

OR

```
for i in Newdict:
    if i['age'] == '20':
        print(i['name'])
```

OR in one line

```
print([i['name'] for i in Newdict if int(i['age']) == 20][0])
```

Output

```
salman
```

Comment: While making Dictionary  from json do i need to declare Dictionary eg d =[ ] d=r.json()

Comment: If the json is a list of dictionaries you can do only the r.json()

Answer (score 1):

There are several dicts in the example, so you probably have some kind of list?
Then you can do something like:

```
[d['name'] for d in dictList if d['age'] == 20]
```

Upd. As Ann Zen pointed out in the comments, this code would return you a list with a single value (or several values, if multiple dicts have `age=20`). If you're sure that there's only one value, that fits your filter, you can add `[0]` in the end, to get first result from that list.

Comment: This will return the name in a list. Add a subscription of `[0]` to only retrieve the name in a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary keys to retrieve their corresponding values:

```
Newdict = [{'name':'jas','surname':'kumar','age':'19','country':'IN'},
           {'name':'arch','surname':'sahu','age':'29','country':'Sl'},
           {'name':'salman','surname':'khan','age':'20','country':'pk'},
           {'name':'raju','surname':'reddy','age':'32','country':'usa'}]

for d in Newdict:
    if int(d['age']) == 20:
        print(d['name'])
```

Output:

```
salman
```