# how to print the key from the dictionary where the values of the dictionary is list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

**How to print the key of the dictionary with the value matches to the value provided**

```
dict1 = {'A': ['1', '2'],'B': ['3', '4']}
val = ['1', '2']
for k, v in dict1.items():
    if v == val:
        print(k)
```

expected output : 'A'

Comment: Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary)

Comment: your code already outputs 'A' by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your code is that you did not add the ending ' for the string when you set the key 'B', and running through the rest of your code, it seems fine. For reference:

```
dict1 = {'A': ['1', '2'],'B': ['3', '4']}
val = ['1', '2']
for k, v in dict1.items():
    if v == val:
        print(k)
```