# How to get key from the value of dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, data-structures, key-value

I have the following set of rules for grading system

```
if 25 < score <= 30, grade = A. 
if 20 < score <= 25, grade = B. 
if 15 < score <= 20, grade = C. 
if 10 < score <= 15, grade = D. 
if 5 < score <= 10, grade = E. 
if 0 <= score <= 5, grade = F.
```

so I have to write a function which takes score as parameter and returns letter grade. So I can do this using selections(if, else). But I want to do it in different manner.
for instance I want to declare a dictionary like below:

```
gradeDict = {
    'A': [26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
    'B': [21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
    'C': [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
    'D': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
    'E': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    'F': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
}
```

so while checking the score with values I want to return the key

In python I've learned something like `dict.get(term, 'otherwise')` but it will give you the values. Is there any other mechanism that does the opposite, ie: if we can pass the value in the get method it will return the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bisect` standard library offers an elegant solution to problems like this one.  In fact, [grading is one of the examples shown in the docs.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html).  Here is an adaption of the example modeled on OP's grading curve:

Example:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

def grade(score, breakpoints=[5, 10, 15, 20, 25], grades='FEDCBA'):
    i = bisect_left(breakpoints, score)
    return grades[i]

[grade(score) for score in [1, 5, 8, 10, 11, 15, 17, 20, 22, 25, 26]]
```

Output:

```
['F', 'F', 'E', 'E', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'A']
```

Comment: This works. what I wanted to do was to reduce a whole lot of if-elses. So the solution you provided rescues.

Comment: It works fine, but if you pass 50 as score it will return A which violets the grading system condition above.

Answer (score 0):

Funny thing is that you don't even need a dictionary for this, just an array. Ofc you can do it in a dictionary way style by declaring the following dict:

```
gradeDict = {
        1:'F',
        2:'E',
        3:'D',
        4:'C',
        5:'B',
        6:'A'
    }
```

This dict seems to be useless since it's just an ordered list of indexes 1,2,3...
You can transform it: `grates_arr = ['F', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']`

But how can I get the letter that I need? you may ask. Simple, divide the score by 5. 21 // 5 means 4. grates_arr[21//5] is 'B'.
2 more particular cases:
when the score divides 5 means you have to subtract 1 because for example 25 // 5 means 5 but grates_arr[5] is A not B.
when score is 0 do not subtract.

Comment: In your approach a string of all letter grades 'FEDCBA'[score // 5] would do the same. But I want that dictionary approach.

Comment: letterGrade = 'FEDCBA'[(score - 1) // 5 if score > 0 else 0]
this is pretty much what you suggested. But Can you help me with the way I asked the question for?

Comment: well, if you really want to use that dictionary which seems to be inefficient take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary

Comment: mydict = {'george': 16, 'amber': 19}
print(list(mydict.keys())[list(mydict.values()).index(16)])
have a look at it
this is pretty much close to what I want. But in my case the value is a list.  is there any way to pass the score in index which will then iterate through the list of values of the dict and will eventually return the key?