# How to get the specific words from CountVectorizer output?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have encoded a text data set using the Sklearn CountVectorizer method, e.g.:

```py
c_vec = CountVectorizer(stop_words=stopwords)
```

where the stop words were generated by `nltk`.

I used `output = c_vec.fit_transform(data)` to encode my dataset. I then want to check what the encoder was doing so ran `print(output)` and got a printout that looks like:

```py
  (0, 3744) 3
  (0, 4511) 2
  (0, 4071) 2
  (0, 1831) 1
  (0, 4321) 2
  (0, 8156) 2
  (0, 7982) 1
  (0, 2714) 1
  (0, 2505) 1
  ...
  (2394, 6070)  1
  (2394, 8559)  2
  (2394, 8087)  1
  (2394, 7997)  8
  (2394, 7827)  1
  (2394, 5159)  5
  (2394, 5396)  1
```

My understanding is that with `(0, 3744) 3`,

- `0` is the line number of the string from the dataset
- `3744` is the encoding of the word
- `3` being the count of that word in the string.

However, I want to be able to see what word is associated with `3744`. I have read the documentation on Sklearn, but can't see what I am looking for. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**: `c_vec.get_feature_names()[3744]` will do your job; read below for the details.

---

Your starting point is the `.vocabulary_` attribute [see **EDIT** at the end for a more straightforward way], which, according to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn-feature-extraction-text-countvectorizer), provides a dictionary with

> A mapping of terms to feature indices.

Adapting the example from the documentation:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
corpus = [
    'This is the first document.',
    'This document is the second document.',
    'And this is the third one.',
    'Is this the first document?',
         ]
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
```

we get

```
print(X)

  (0, 8)    1
  (0, 3)    1
  (0, 6)    1
  (0, 2)    1
  (0, 1)    1
  (1, 8)    1
  (1, 3)    1
  (1, 6)    1
  (1, 1)    2
  (1, 5)    1
  (2, 8)    1
  (2, 3)    1
  (2, 6)    1
  (2, 0)    1
  (2, 7)    1
  (2, 4)    1
  (3, 8)    1
  (3, 3)    1
  (3, 6)    1
  (3, 2)    1
  (3, 1)    1
```

and

```
vectorizer.vocabulary_

{'and': 0,
 'document': 1,
 'first': 2,
 'is': 3,
 'one': 4,
 'second': 5,
 'the': 6,
 'third': 7,
 'this': 8}
```

So, now your problem has become how to find the dictionary *key* with a given value.

Modifying `method3` from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14624923/4685471) (since it does not seem to work with Python 3):

```
def get_term(dict, search_index):
    return list(dict.keys())[list(dict.values()).index(search_index)]
```

we get:

```
get_term(vectorizer.vocabulary_, 8)
# 'this'

get_term(vectorizer.vocabulary_, 5)
# 'second'
```

i.e. exactly what you are after.

Notice that the `get_term()` function will return only the *first* key with the given value; nevertheless, in the specific case here where the dictionary is a *vocabulary*, this is not an issue, since by definition the *values* are unique, as it can be easily confirmed from a simple inspection.

Notice also that, although there are some alternatives to `method3` in the SO answer linked above, the said method is by far the fastest when it comes to big dictionaries (as is the case with such NLP applications in real-world corpora).

**EDIT**

As correctly suggested by Ben Reiniger in the comments below, a more straightforward way to get the vocabulary term that corresponds to the `k` column of the document-term matrix `X` is the `k` element of `get_feature_names()`:

```
names_ = vectorizer.get_feature_names() # run it once, as it is costly for large vocabularies
names_[8]
# 'this'

names_[5]
# 'second'
```

Comment: `get_feature_names` already inverts the `vocabulary_` internally, although it maybe doesn't use the most efficient method?...

Comment: @BenReiniger seems correct, too, and certainly more straightforward; didn't check efficiencies, but I would be surprised if it is *less* efficient. You'll post an answer, or I'll update mine to include this possibility?