# Iterate through a Python Dictionary and delete a particular element if matches a specific string

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary like-

```
mydict = {
  'users': [
    {
      'userid': 'u1234',
      'name': 'user1'
    },
    {
      'userid': 'u0007',
      'name': 'user2'
    }
  ]
}
```

I want a functionality  such that if I pass userid=u1234 it should iterate through the dictionary and delete the  details for that userid from the dictionary and then write the output to a file.

Comment: Hi @user2242660, here's a relevant discussion about finding dictionary keys using values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:-

```
for i,v in mydict.items():
    for a in v:
        if (a['userid'] == 'u1234'):
            v.remove(a)
```

Then use following code to write to a file:-

```
import json
with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(mydict, fp)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the prompt response. It is working like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

This code will handle your request of deleting a specific user:

```py
for user in mydict['users']:
    if user['userid'] == 'u1234':
        mydict['users'].remove(user)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd simplify:

```
user_list = myDict['users']
for usr_dict in user_list:
  if usr_dict['name'] = name_to_remove:
    myDict['users'].remove(usr_dict)
```

Also, zooming out one step to improve lookup efficiency (and loop simplicity), you could [re-]structure your `myDict` as so:

```
users_dict = {
       'u1234': {
              'userid': 'u1234'
              'name': 'user1'
        },
        'u0007': {
              'userid': 'u0007'
              'name': 'user2'
        }
}
```

then your loop could become:

```
for uid, obj in users_dict.items():
  if obj['name'] == username_to_delete:
    users_dict.remove(uid)
```