# python getting json values from list

Tags: python, json

I have some json data similar to this...

```
    {
        "people": [
            {
                "name": "billy",
                "age": "12"
                 ...
                 ...
            },
            {
                "name": "karl",
                "age": "31"
                 ...
                 ...
            },
            ...
            ...
        ]
    }
```

At the moment I can do this to get a entry from the people list...

```
wantedPerson = "karl"

for person in people:
    if person['name'] == wantedPerson:
        * I have the persons entry *
        break
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Something similar to how we can `.get('key')` ?
Thanks,
Chris

Comment: What you are doing makes sense.

Comment: If you want to do this search multiple times, you could re-structure the data first.  Otherwise there isn't any improvement to make. Keep in mind that there is no such thing as "a json object" - json *data* is parsed to create *ordinary* Python `dict`s, `list`s etc. After that, the rules are exactly the same as if you had created the data *in any other way*.

Comment: OK thanks guys. Also, I changed object for data.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you load that json data using the standard library for it, you're fairly close to optimal, perhaps you were looking for something like this:

```
from json import loads

text = '{"people": [{"name": "billy", "age": "12"}, {"name": "karl", "age": "31"}]}'

data = loads(text)

people = [p for p in data['people'] if p['name'] == 'karl']
```

If you frequently need to access this data, you might just do something like this:

```
all_people = {p['name']: p for p in data['people']}

print(all_people['karl'])
```

That is, `all_people` becomes a dictionary that uses the name as a key, so you can access any person in it quickly by accessing them by name. This assumes however that there are no duplicate names in your data.

Answer (score 1):

First, there's no problem with your current 'naive' approach - it's clear and efficient since you can't find the value you're looking for without scanning the list.

It seems that you refer to better as shorter, so if you want a one-liner solution, consider the following:

```
next((person for person in people if person.name == wantedPerson), None)
```

It gets the first person in the list that has the required name or `None` if no such person was found.

Answer (score 0):

similarly

```
ps =  {
        "people": [
            {
                "name": "billy",
                "age": "12"
    
            },
            {
                "name": "karl",
                "age": "31"
            },
        ]
    }

print([x for x in ps['people'] if 'karl' in x.values()])
```

For possible alternatives or details see e.g. # [Get key by value in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary)