# KeyError: 'data'

Tags: python, api, python-requests, controlpanel

I am currently on a Discord Bot interacting with the Controlpanel API. (https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/9044962/TzY69ub2#02b8da43-ab01-487d-b2f5-5f8699b509cd)

Now, I am getting an KeyError when listing a specific user.

```
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer <censored>'
}

url = "https://<censored>"
endpoint = f"/api/users/{user}"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = requests.get(f'{url}{endpoint}', headers=headers).text
    for user in json.loads(data)['data']:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Users")
        embed.add_field(name=user['id'], value=user['name'])
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

^That's python.

Error:

```
for user in json.loads(data)['data']:
```

KeyError: 'data'

How can I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Print out the dictionary from the output json.loads(data). Does it have the data key?

Comment: There is no 'data' key in your json.loads(data) because your code is correct

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get key by value in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary)

Comment: `Response` objects from `requests` have a `json` method that will return a python object. You don't need to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

This KeyError happens usually when the Key doesn't exist(not exist or even a typo). in your case I think you dont have the 'data' key in your response and your should use something like:

```
data.json()
```

if you can post the complete response it would be more convinient to give you some hints.

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint you're hitting does not return a list but a single object.

You should use the generic endpoint : `{{url}}/api/users`

Also I don't think you want to recreate your `embed` object for each user.

```py
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer <censored>'
}

url = 'https://<censored>'
endpoint = '/api/users'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Users")
    for user in requests.get(
        f'{url}{endpoint}', headers=headers
    ).json()['data']:
        embed.add_field(name=user['id'], value=user['name'])
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Also I'm pretty sure you can't just `await` like that in `__main__`.