# How can I fetch a value from a JSON dictionary?

Tags: json, loops, dictionary, jinja2, salt-stack

I am trying to grab the value `green` from the below JSON data dictionary.

The API endpoint located at http://localhost:9200/api/status give the below data:

```json
{
   "name":"prod01",
   "uuid":"3430c40-e786-4325-bc48-e0a096956000",
   "version":{
      "number":"7.17.0",
      "build_hash":"60a9838d21b6420bbdb5a4d07099111b74c68ceb",
      "build_number":46534,
      "build_snapshot":false
   },
   "status":{
      "overall":{
         "since":"2023-02-13T22:47:05.381Z",
         "state":"green",
         "title":"Green",
         "nickname":"Looking good",
         "icon":"success",
         "uiColor":"secondary"
      },
      "statuses":[
         {
            "id":"core:elasticsearch@7.17.0",
            "message":"Elasticsearch is available",
            "since":"2023-02-13T22:47:05.381Z",
            "state":"green",
            "icon":"success",
            "uiColor":"secondary"
         },
         {
            "id":"core:savedObjects@7.17.0",
            "message":"SavedObjects service has completed migrations and is available",
            "since":"2023-02-13T22:47:05.381Z",
            "state":"green",
            "icon":"success",
            "uiColor":"secondary"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

And the test.sls file doing the job is:

```
{% set json_data = salt.cp.get_url('http://localhost:9200/api/status', dest=None) | load_json %}

{% for key, value in json_data.items() %}
{% if value['state'] == 'green' %}
{{ key }}: {{ value }} (found)
{% else %}
{{ key }}: {{ value }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Executing it, I get the error:

> Rendering SLS 'base:svr.salt.dev.test' failed: Jinja variable 'str object' has no attribute 'state'

Comment: Hi. the JSON sample posted in question seems incomplete and its not possible to reproduce what you are trying to do. That said, you can try using [HTTP module](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/tutorials/http.html) which will give access to a dict containing the JSON output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get key by value in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

You are looping on all the key-value pairs of the object `json_data`, with `json_data.items()`, so, you do not have a `my_dictionary['state']` anymore, what you have is a `key` which will be `state` and its value will be `green`.

This said, your `{"state": "green"}` is not in the root of your dictionary, so you will never find any key-value pair matching what you need.

What you can do, though is:

```
{% if load_json.status.overall.state == 'green' -%}
  state: {{ load_json.status.overall.nickname }}
{% endif %}
```

Which would yield:

```
state: Looking good
```

Comment: I made change as per your suggestion:

{% set json_data = salt.cp.get_url('http://localhost:9200/api/status', 
dest=None) | load_json %}
{% if json_data.status.overall.state == 'green' %}
  {{ json_data.status.overall.nickname }}
{% endif %}
but got below error :

Data failed to compile:Rendering SLS 'base::svr.salt.dev.test3' does not render to a dictionary.
Error when rendering state with contents: Looking good

Comment: As the message clearly points out, it seems a `sls` file in Salt needs to be a YAML, is, see the updated answer to have a valid YAML.