# Swap dictionary keys and values when values are lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

Similarly to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031851/python-best-way-to-exchange-keys-with-values-in-a-dictionary) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483666/python-reverse-inverse-a-mapping), I'd like to swap keys and values in a dictionary.

The difference is, my values are lists, not just single values.

Thus, I'd like to turn:

```
In [120]: swapdict = dict(foo=['a', 'b'], bar=['c', 'd'])

In [121]: swapdict
Out[121]: {'bar': ['c', 'd'], 'foo': ['a', 'b']}
```

into:

```
{'a': 'foo', 'b': 'foo', 'c': 'bar', 'd': 'bar'}
```

Let's assume I'm happy that my values are unique.

Comment: `{k: oldk for oldk, oldv in swapdict.items() for k in oldv}` - I haven't tested this, but I think it will work

Comment: @Alik Yep! Seems to work just fine.

Comment: If anyone would like to add this as an answer I'll accept it. Otherwise I'll do it myself in a day or two!

Comment: @Alik i think you should answer it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) and the [`.items()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) method.

```
In []: {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in swapdict.items() for k in oldv}
Out[]: {'a': 'foo', 'b': 'foo', 'c': 'bar', 'd': 'bar'}
```