# get median on groups of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to be able to calculate median on group of columns in a dataframe. I have the following example dataframe. For my actual dataframe, number of columns, names of columns and groups are dynamic as it depends on the user input.

```
raw_data= {'a':['g1','g2','g3','g4','g5'],'b':[10,11,12,13,14],'c':[5,6,7,8,9],'d':[112,1,0,9,8],'e':[6,7,8,0,9],'f':[0,1,6,7,8],'g':[9,8,6,5,4]}
mydf= pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
newdf= mydf.set_index('a')
```

I have another dictionary where I store group information for my columns

```
gp_dict= {'gp1':['b','c','d'],'gp2':['e','f','g']}
```

Current dataframe:

```
     b  c    d  e  f  g
a                      
g1  10  5  112  6  0  9
g2  11  6    1  7  1  8
g3  12  7    0  8  6  6
g4  13  8    9  0  7  5
g5  14  9    8  9  8  4
```

My code should get median for each group and keep rows if Median greater than 8 for any of the groups.

Desired output:

```
     b  c    d  e  f  g
g1  10  5  112  6  0  9
g4  13  8    9  0  7  5
g5  14  9    8  9  8  4
```

Obviously, intermediate step should be to calcuate median on both groups:

```
     b  c    d  e  f  g Median_gp1 Median_gp2
g1  10  5  112  6  0  9    10         6
g2  11  6    1  7  1  8    6          7
g3  12  7    0  8  6  6    7          6
g4  13  8    9  0  7  5    9          5
g5  14  9    8  9  8  4    9          8
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `groupby` by swapped dict by columns, aggregate `median` and compare with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for at least one `True` per row. Last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
#swap key values in dict
#http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674731/2901002
d = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in gp_dict.items() for k in oldv}
mask = newdf.groupby(d, axis=1).median().gt(8).any(1)
#same as
#mask = (newdf.groupby(d, axis=1).median() > 8).any(1)
print (newdf[mask])
     b  c    d  e  f  g
a                      
g1  10  5  112  6  0  9
g4  13  8    9  0  7  5
g5  14  9    8  9  8  4
```

Comment: Very nice, the solution reads almost like natural language: "I want to groupby, then get the median, check if it is greater than 8 for any row"

Comment: I didn't know you could pass a dictionary to `groupby`... that's cool!