# Pandas: how do I group a Data Frame by a set of ordinal values?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, group-by

I'm starting to learn about Python *Pandas* and want to generate a graph with the sum of arbitrary groupings of an ordinal value. It can be better explained with a simple example.

Suppose I have the following table of food consumption data:

[image]

And I have two groups of foods defined as two lists:

```
healthy = ['apple', 'brocolli']
junk = ['cheetos', 'coke']
```

Now I want to plot a graph with the evolution of consumption of junk and healthy food. I believe I must then process my data to get a DataFrame like:

[image]

Suppose the first table is already in a Dataframe called `food`, how do I transform it to get the second one?

I also welcome suggestions to reword my question to make it clearer, or for different approaches to generate the plot.

Comment: Please don't post images of data, for [many reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), among them that it means anyone who wants to show a worked example with your data has to type it in manually.

Comment: @DSM: lesson learned. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First create `dictinary` with lists and then swap `keys` with `values`.

Then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by mapped column `food` by `dict` and `year`, aggregate `sum` and last reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
healthy = ['apple', 'brocolli']
junk = ['cheetos', 'coke']

d1 = {'healthy':healthy, 'junk':junk}
##http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674731/2901002
d = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d1.items() for k in oldv}
print (d)
{'brocolli': 'healthy', 'cheetos': 'junk', 'apple': 'healthy', 'coke': 'junk'}

df1 = df.groupby([df.food.map(d), 'year'])['amount'].sum().unstack(0)
print (df1)
food  healthy  junk
year               
2010       10    11
2011       17    10
2012       13    24
```

Another solution with [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index='year', columns=df.food.map(d), values='amount', aggfunc='sum')
print (df1)
food  healthy  junk
year               
2010       10    11
2011       17    10
2012       13    24
```

Comment: Going to sleep early tonight... have fun :-)

Comment: Ya, yesterday it was crazy ;) Good night ;)

Comment: Thanks, I loved pivot tables. Here is a good guide to understand: http://nikgrozev.com/2015/07/01/reshaping-in-pandas-pivot-pivot-table-stack-and-unstack-explained-with-pictures/