# How to replace dataframe column values with dictionary keys?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

Suppose I have a dictionary:

```
dict = {"1" : "A", "2" : "B" , "3" : "C"}
```

and a data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["ID"] = pd.Series(["A","B","C"])
df["Desc"] = pd.Series(["Fruits","Vegs","Meat"])
```

The dataframe will look like this:

[image]

How would I replace values in column `df["ID"]` with dictionary keys so that I have `1,2,3` in `df["ID"]` instead of `A,B,C`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First create a reverse mapping:

```
In [363]: dict2 = {v : k for k, v in dict_.items()}
```

The assumption made here is that your values are unique. Now you can use `pd.Series.replace`:

```
In [367]: df.ID = df.ID.replace(dict2); df
Out[367]: 
  ID    Desc
0  1  Fruits
1  2    Vegs
2  3    Meat
```

---

Alternative solution with `pd.Series.map`:

```
In [380]: df.ID = df.ID.map(dict2); df
Out[380]: 
  ID    Desc
0  1  Fruits
1  2    Vegs
2  3    Meat
```

Also, I recommend you use a different name than `dict`, because there's already a builtin with that name.

Comment: how would you do it if your values in your dictionary are a list? Say you found the value in the original dataframe to replace as a value in a list under a key. How would you replace it with that key? I tried your approach, but the first line gives me this error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: @florence-y I'd like a little more information. Can you open a new question with an [mcve] and link me to it? I think you might need to use a list comprehension but I can't be sure without some testing.

Comment: I managed to figure this out on my own -- I played around a bit and got the keys and values to switch with `dict2 = {keys: old_keys for old_keys, old_values in dict.items() for keys in old_values}`, then used `df.columnheader.replace(dict2)` to get what I needed. This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674403/swap-dictionary-keys-and-values-when-values-are-lists) helped me, then I used `pd.Series.replace`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Or you can just base on pandas .

```
df.ID=df.ID.map((pd.DataFrame(data=d,index=['Value',]).T.reset_index().set_index('Value'))['index'])

Out[23]: 
  ID    Desc
0  1  Fruits
1  2    Vegs
2  3    Meat
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be:

```
dict1 = pd.DataFrame(dict.items())
dict1.columns = ['ID_1',"ID"]
merge = pd.merge(df,dict1)
del merge['ID']
merge = merge.rename(columns={'ID_1': 'ID'})

    Desc    ID
0   Fruits  1
1   Vegs    2
2   Meat    3
```