# Swap dictionary keys and values, when values are lists and items are not unique

Tags: python, dictionary, key

**Set-up**

I have a large dictionary with unique keys, unique values and non-unique values in lists.

Dictionary looks like,

```
d = {'a': ['1','2','3'],'b': ['1'],'c': ['1','3']}
```

---

**Problem**

I'd like to swap the keys and values such that,

```
d_inverse = {'1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], '2': ['a'],'3': ['a', 'c']}
```

I've found the following answers about swapping keys and values,

- [Python reverse / invert a mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483666/python-reverse-invert-a-mapping)

and about swapping keys with values in lists,

- [Swap dictionary keys and values when values are lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674403/swap-dictionary-keys-and-values-when-values-are-lists)

the last answer comes close, but doesn't manage non-unique values in lists.

That is,

```
{k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d.items() for k in oldv}
```

produces

```
{'1': 'c', '2': 'a', '3': 'c'}
```

How do I account for the non-unique values and don't lose information?

Comment: Consider using a loop?

Comment: Note you have both `int` and `string` values in the lists in `d`, so your output isn't quite right (it should have both `'1'` and `1` keys).

Comment: Thanks, I edited my example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
d = {'a': ['1','2','3'],'b': ['1'],'c': ['1','3']}

from collections import defaultdict
d_dict = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in d.items():
    for i in v:
        d_dict[i].append(k)

dict(d_dict)
#{'1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], '2': ['a'], '3': ['a', 'c']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `for-loop`

```
d = {'a': ['1','2','3'],'b': [1],'c': ['1','3']}
res = {}

for k,v in d.items():           #Iterate dictionary.
    for i in v:                 #Iterate List
        i = str(i)              #Convert element to string
        if i not in res:        #Check if key in dictionary.
            res[i] = [k]
        else:
            res[i].append(k)    #Else append element. 
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
{'1': ['a', 'c', 'b'], '3': ['a', 'c'], '2': ['a']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/485368/9544516)

```
inv_map = {}
for k, v in my_map.iteritems():
    inv_map.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
```

with a small change it works as we want:

```
d = {'a': ['1','2','3'],'b': ['1'],'c': ['1','3']}

inv_map = {}
for k, vs in d.items():
    for v in vs:
        inv_map.setdefault(v, []).append(k)


print(inv_map)
>>> {'1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], '2': ['a'], '3': ['a', 'c']}
```

Comment: Thanks Maarten. I found that one, but doesn't work. `list` is not hashable.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a dictionary comprehension:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet
d = {'a': ['1','2','3'],'b': ['1'],'c': ['1','3']}
new_d = {str(alphabet.index(a)+1):[alphabet[int(i)-1] for i in b] for a, b in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], '2': ['a'], '3': ['a', 'c']}
```