# To get the entries from one column of dataframe, segregate on its properties and place them to a different columns according to that property

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file which i have converted in dataframe and input file looks like this:

```
    Date     Area    Input
4/5/2019    Forest  apple
4/5/2019    Forest  banana
4/5/2019    Forest  Lion
4/5/2019    Town    banana
4/6/2019    Town    dog
4/6/2019    Town    grapes
4/6/2019    Town    cat
```

I need an output like this which displays count of fruits and animals in seperate Fruits and Animals Columns based on Date and Area:

```
    Date    Area    Fruits  Animals
4/5/2019    Forest  2       1
4/5/2019    Town    1       0
4/6/2019    Forest  0       0
4/6/2019    Town    1       2
```

The code I have written:

```
1.Conversion of date format

date_final='2019-04-05'
data_to_analyse1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data_to_analyse1['date'],format= 
'%Y-%m-%d')
data_to_analyse2= 
data_to_analyse1.loc[(data_to_analyse1['date']==date_final)]

2.To read Input column based on date and area:

for a in Area:
    intent_name=data_to_analyse2.loc[data_to_analyse2['Area'] ==  a]
    intent_list=list(intent_name['Input'])

3.Then to count entries in 'Input' column I am using count for each unique 
entry like this:

Intent_IsNull=intent_list.count('Intent_IsNull')
apple=intent_list.count('apple')
banana=intent_list.count('banana')
lion=intent_list.count('lion')
dog=intent_list.count('dog')
grapes=intent_list.count('grapes')
cat=intent_list.count('cat')
```

Requirement(what my code does not do):

```
I am able to make each columns seperately But I have not find 
a way here to put (apples,banana,grapes) in one column called 'Fruits' and 
(elephant,lion,cat,dog) in one column called 'Animals' as shown in output 
above
```

How it could be done in context of my code, any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create dictionary of [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to catagories, count values by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
d = {'apple':'Fruits','banana':'Fruits','grapes':'Fruits',
     'Lion':'Animals','dog':'Animals','cat':'Animals'}
m = df['Input'].map(d)

df = df.groupby(['Date','Area', m]).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Last add missing `Date` with `Area` combinations by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
df = (df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels, names=df.index.names), 
                 fill_value=0)
        .reset_index())
print (df)
Input      Date    Area  Animals  Fruits
0      4/5/2019  Forest        1       2
1      4/5/2019    Town        0       1
2      4/6/2019  Forest        0       0
3      4/6/2019    Town        2       1
```

Another solution with `map` and [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and append missing `Date` and `Area` combinations by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
m = df['Input'].map(d)
df = pd.crosstab([df['Date'],df['Area']], m).unstack(fill_value=0).stack().reset_index()
print (df)
Input      Date    Area  Animals  Fruits
0      4/5/2019  Forest        1       2
1      4/5/2019    Town        0       1
2      4/6/2019  Forest        0       0
3      4/6/2019    Town        2       1
```

EDIT:

Format of dictonary is possible change to values in list, but need parse it to `key`:`value` before `map`:

```
d1 = {'Fruits':['apple','banana','grapes'],
      'Animals':['Lion','dog','cat']}

#http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674731/2901002
d = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d1.items() for k in oldv}

print (d)
{'apple': 'Fruits', 'banana': 'Fruits', 'grapes': 'Fruits', 
 'Lion': 'Animals', 'dog': 'Animals', 'cat': 'Animals'}
```

EDIT1:

If need count each value separately:

```
df = pd.crosstab([df['Date'],df['Area']], df['Input']).unstack(fill_value=0).stack()
print (df)
Input            Lion  apple  banana  cat  dog  grapes
Date     Area                                         
4/5/2019 Forest     1      1       1    0    0       0
         Town       0      0       1    0    0       0
4/6/2019 Forest     0      0       0    0    0       0
         Town       0      0       0    1    1       1
```

Then `rename` and get `sum` per columns:

```
df = df.rename(columns=d).sum(axis=1, level=0).reset_index()
print (df)
Input      Date    Area  Animals  Fruits
0      4/5/2019  Forest        1       2
1      4/5/2019    Town        0       1
2      4/6/2019  Forest        0       0
3      4/6/2019    Town        2       1
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.... Can the dictionary be made like this that one key that is fruit have list of all values of fruits like:
d={'Fruits': 'list1'} where list1 has content banana,apple and grapes. And same with that with animals?

Comment: @SachinKumar - It is possible, but need step for change it to `d = {'apple':'Fruits','banana':'Fruits','grapes':'Fruits',
     'Lion':'Animals','dog':'Animals','cat':'Animals'}` format.

Comment: @SachinKumar - Edited answer.

Comment: In this way it works... but can you help me know that the way I had done like counting individually in my code, is there a way in that case to merge all fruits and animals in separate columns? any insights of yours in this would work to figure out my error

Comment: @SachinKumar - Added code for it. Basically, problem of your code are after get final lists by `Intent_IsNull=intent_list.count('Intent_IsNull')
apple=intent_list.count('apple')
banana=intent_list.count('banana')
lion=intent_list.count('lion')
dog=intent_list.count('dog')
grapes=intent_list.count('grapes')
cat=intent_list.count('cat')`, lost information about date and are. Aslo loops in pandas are not recomenned, because slow.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to give my solution. It seems easier..

```
d = {'apple':'Fruits','banana':'Fruits','grapes':'Fruits','Lion':'Animals','dog':'Animals','cat':'Animals'}
df['Ewa']= df['Input'].map(d)
df.head(3)
```

[image]

```
df.pivot_table(index=['Date','Area'],columns='Ewa',aggfunc='count').reset_index()
```

[image]