# Where column is equal to a specific value, insert new value into new column - Python

Tags: python, pandas, where-clause

I am trying to create a new `column` that contains values based off values in a separate `column`. Specifically, for the `df` below, where value in `['Val'] ==  'A','B','C'` I want to insert `'X'` into `['New_Val']`. Similar for `'D','E','F'` but insert a `'Y'`

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'Val' : ['A','B','C','D','E','F'],                                     
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

Xs = ['A','B','C']
Ys = ['D','E','F']

df['New_Val'] = df.loc['New_Val'].loc[df['Val'] == Xs] = 'X'
df['New_Val'] = df.loc['New_Val'].loc[df['Val'] == Ys] = 'Y'
```

Intended Output:

```
  Val New_Val
0   A       X
1   B       X
2   C       X
3   D       Y
4   E       Y
5   F       Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary:

```
#specify values
d = {'X':Xs, 'Y':Ys}
print (d)
{'X': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Y': ['D', 'E', 'F']}

#swap key values in dict of lists
#http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674731/2901002
d1 = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d.items() for k in oldv}
print (d1)
{'A': 'X', 'B': 'X', 'C': 'X', 'D': 'Y', 'E': 'Y', 'F': 'Y'}


df['New_Val'] = df['Val'].map(d1)
print (df)
  Val New_Val
0   A       X
1   B       X
2   C       X
3   D       Y
4   E       Y
5   F       Y
```