# Pandas wide to long with additional dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this

```
>df
ds           A  B  C
01/01/2010   4  2  1
02/01/2010   2  9  3
03/01/2010   1  3  0
```

Where A & B belong to Category 1 and C is Category 2.

I want to convert it into:

```
ds           Category  Company  Value
01/01/2010      1         A      4
01/01/2010      1         B      2
01/01/2010      2         C      1
```

and so on, for plotting later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
df['ds'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ds'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

df = df.melt('ds', var_name='Company')
```

If multiple categories is possible create dictionary and create new column by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
d = {1:['A','B'], 2:['C']}
#swap key values in dict
#http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674731/2901002
d1 = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d.items() for k in oldv}

df['Category'] = df['Company'].map(d1)

#alternative1
#df['Category'] = np.where(df['Company'] == 'C', 2, 1)
#alternative2
#df['Category'] = np.where(df['Company'].isin(['A','B']), 1, 2)
```

---

```
df = df.sort_values(['ds','Company']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Or [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df['ds'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ds'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

df = df.set_index('ds').stack().rename_axis(('ds','Company')).reset_index(name='value')
df['Category'] = np.where(df['Company'] == 'C', 2, 1)
```

---

```
print (df)
          ds Company  value  Category
0 2010-01-01       A      4         1
1 2010-01-01       B      2         1
2 2010-01-01       C      1         2
3 2010-01-02       A      2         1
4 2010-01-02       B      9         1
5 2010-01-02       C      3         2
6 2010-01-03       A      1         1
7 2010-01-03       B      3         1
8 2010-01-03       C      0         2
```

Comment: Thank You. 1 follow up question. If number of categories are more than two (say 10 companies and 4 categories, how can i put multiple np.where arguments)

Comment: @Martan - added solution with dictionary of lists for categories.

Answer (score 1):

We can use [pd.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) followed by 
[np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) :

```
df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['ds'], value_vars=['A', 'B', 'C'])

df2['Category'] = np.where((df2['variable'] == 'A') | (df2['variable'] == 'B'), 1, 2)
```