# Use a different dataframe to replace value of text in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple dataframe (df1) where I am replacing values with the replace function (see below). Instead of always having to change the names of the items I want to replace in the code, I would like this to be done from an excel sheet, where either the columns or rows give the different names that should be replaced. I would import the excel as a dataframe (df2). All I am missing is the scrip that would turn the info from df2 into the replace function.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Product':['Tart', 'Cookie', 'Black'],
                   'Quantity': [1234, 4, 333]})

print(df1)
  Product  Quantity
0      Tart      1234
1      Cookie    4
2      Black     333
```

This is what I used so far

```
sales = sales.replace (["Tart","Tart2", "Cookie", "Cookie2"], "Tartlet")
sales = sales.replace (["Ham and cheese Sandwich" , "Chicken focaccia"], "Sandwich")
```

After replacement

```
print(df1)
  Product  Quantity
0      Tartlet   1234
1      Tartlet    4
2      Black     333
```

This is how my dataframe 2 could look like (I am flexible how to design it) after I imported it from an excel file

```
df2 = pd.read_excel (setup_folder / "Product Replacements.xlsx", index_col= 0)

print (df2)
      Tartlet  Sandwich
0      Tart      Ham and cheese Sandwich
1      Tart2    Chicken Focaccia
2      Cookie2     nan
```

Comment: try openpyxl library for reading from excel files.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Tartlet':['Tart', 'Tart2', 'Cookie'],
                    'Sandwich': ['Ham and Cheese Sandwich', 'Chicken Focaccia', 'another']})

#swap key values in dict
#http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674731/2901002
d1 = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in df2.items() for k in oldv}
print (d1)
{'Tart': 'Tartlet', 'Tart2': 'Tartlet', 'Cookie': 'Tartlet', 'Ham and Cheese Sandwich': 
 'Sandwich', 'Chicken Focaccia': 'Sandwich', 'another': 'Sandwich'}

df1['Product'] = df1['Product'].replace(d1)
#for improve performance
#df1['Product'] = df1['Product'].map(d1).fillna(df1['Product'])
print (df1)
   Product  Quantity
0  Tartlet      1234
1  Tartlet         4
2    Black       333
```

Comment: Thank you. I see that you created another name for the Sandwich key. Yet what can I do if I do not have the same number of replacements. What if I do not want to use another name like "another"? I noticed that if my array is not the same, it will create a key "nan". Any idea how I can delete this one then?

Comment: On a second note, once I add (pd.read_excel) the dataframe that I turn into a dictionary, the replacement no longer works,. Any idea?

Comment: @ManuH Use `df2 = {data[column].name: [y for y in data[column] if not pd.isna(y)] for column in data}`

Comment: Sorry, but I am not following. What should I replace the "data" and "name" with?