# Create a new column from another column in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe in python, let's call it `df`

In this dataframe I create a new column based on an exist column as follows:

```
df.loc[:, 'new_col'] = df['col']
```

Then I do the following:

```
df[df['new_col']=='Above Average'] = 'Good'
```

However, I noticed that this operation also changes the values in `df['col']`

What should I do in order the values in `df['col']` not to be affected by operations I do in  `df['new_col']` ?

Comment: I tried and does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df.loc[df['new_col']=='Above Average', 'new_col'] = 'Good'
```

If no column is specified, all columns are set to `Good` by condition.

---

Also both line of code should be changed to one by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) or [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['new_col'] = np.where(df['new_col']=='Above Average', 'Good', df['col'])
```

---

```
df['new_col'] = df['col'].mask(df['new_col']=='Above Average', 'Good')
```

EDIT: For change many values use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) or [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with dictionary for specified values:

```
d = {'Good':['Above average','effective'], 'Very Good':['Really effective']}

#swap key values in dict
#http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674731/2901002
d1 = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d.items() for k in oldv}
print (d1)
{'Above average': 'Good', 'effective': 'Good', 'Really effective': 'Very Good'}

df['new_col'] = df['col'].replace(d1)
#if large data obviously better performance
df['new_col'] = df['col'].map(d1).fillna(df['col'])
```

Comment: And what if I have multiple conditions say, change `Above average` and `effective` both to `Good`, and secondly what if I have other cases ? say `Really effective` to become 'very Good', as an example.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an option to use dataframe [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) method:

```
df['new_col'] = df['col']
df['new_col'].where(df['new_col']!='Above Average', other='Good', inplace=True )
```

But to be clear [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is the fastest way to go:

```
m = df['col'] == 'Above Average'
df['new_column'] = np.where(m, 'Good', df['col'])
```

`df['new_column']` is the new column name. If mask `m` is `True` `df['col']` will be assigned else `'Good'`.

---

```
+----+---------------+
|    | col           |
|----+---------------|
|  0 | Nan           |
|  1 | Above Average |
|  2 | 1.0           |
+----+---------------+
+----+---------------+--------------+
|    | col           | new_column   |
|----+---------------+--------------|
|  0 | Nan           | Nan          |
|  1 | Above Average | Good         |
|  2 | 1.0           | 1.0          |
+----+---------------+--------------+
```

I am also providing here some notes on masking when using the `df.loc`:

```
m = df['col']=='Above Average'
print(m)
df.loc[m, 'new_column'] = 'Good'
```

As you may see the result will be the same, but note how mask `m` is having the information where to read the value if `m` is `False`