# How do I group up data based off a dictionary key with list values?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have an excel file that contains what we can call Serial Prefixes.

This is my input.

```
PFX_CD   SERIAL             STATUS
PR7     PR700300        NB RJ SR XR RC NV
6QN     6QN00274        NB AC NV NS AA FA
MSR     MSR00443        NB AC NV NS AA FA
MSR     MSR00450        NB AC NV NS AA FA
ER9     ER900471        NB AC NV NS AA FA
```

if I have dictionaries like the ones below

```
manulocation = {
    '115':['PR7', '6QN'],
    '116':['MSR', 'TK9', 'GGG'],
    '117':['ER9', 'NNA',]
}
```

How can I group up the data with a new column by it's key? Like so.

This is my sought after output

```
PFX_CD   SERIAL             STATUS          Line
PR7     PR700300        NB RJ SR XR RC NV   115
6QN     6QN00274        NB AC NV NS AA FA   115
MSR     MSR00443        NB AC NV NS AA FA   116
MSR     MSR00450        NB AC NV NS AA FA   116
ER9     ER900471        NB AC NV NS AA FA   117
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with swapped keys and lists in dictioanry for 'flatten' dictionary, only necessary unique values in all lists:

```
#http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674731/2901002
d = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in manulocation.items() for k in oldv}
print (d)

{'PR7': '115', '6QN': '115', 'MSR': '116', 
 'TK9': '116', 'GGG': '116', 'ER9': '117', 'NNA': '117'}

df['Line'] = df['PFX_CD'].map(d)
print (df)

  PFX_CD    SERIAL             STATUS Line
0    PR7  PR700300  NB RJ SR XR RC NV  115
1    6QN  6QN00274  NB AC NV NS AA FA  115
2    MSR  MSR00443  NB AC NV NS AA FA  116
3    MSR  MSR00450  NB AC NV NS AA FA  116
4    ER9  ER900471  NB AC NV NS AA FA  117
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you for the link to the explanation. I was clearly just struggling to search it.

I can now do analysis off of that change right? Because after this code runs, my data frame still contains the original details, it's just joined with the line?

Comment: @Timothyjames67 - Not sure if understand `after this code runs, my data frame still contains the original details`, can you explain more?

Comment: Does my dataframe now contain both the original column and data set and it now has the Line dataset? 

i.e. I can run processes/groupings off of line now?

Comment: @Timothyjames67 - I think yes, if need another column name only chnge it by `df['Anoth col'] = df['PFX_CD'].map(d)`

Comment: very interesting. Thank you for this!