# How to replace cell in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe created from CSV with the following headers:

```
podcast_name,user_name,description,image,ratings,category,itunes_link,rss,email,latest_date,listener_1,listener_2,listener_3,listener_4,listener_5,listener_6,listener_7,listener_8,listener_9,listener_10,listener_11,listener_12,listener_13,listener_14,listener_15,listener_16,listener_17,listener_18
```

This dataframe was loaded from several files and cleared of duplicates:

```py
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join("data/*.csv"))
df = pandas.concat((pandas.read_csv(f) for f in all_files))
df.drop_duplicates(keep=False, inplace=True)
```

Now i want to check and replace some values from `category`. For example i have keywords dict:

```py
categories = {
    "Comedy": ["Comedy Interviews", "Improv", "Stand-Up"],
    "Fiction": ["Comedy Fiction", "Drama", "Science Fiction"]
}
```

So i want to check if value in `category` is equal to one of values from the list. For example i have line with `Improv` in `caterogy` column and i want to replace `Improv` with `Comedy`.

Honestly, I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create helper dictionary and `replace`:

```
#swap key values in dict
#http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674731/2901002
d = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in categories.items() for k in oldv}
print (d)
{'Comedy Interviews': 'Comedy', 'Improv': 'Comedy', 
 'Stand-Up': 'Comedy', 'Comedy Fiction': 'Fiction',
 'Drama': 'Fiction', 'Science Fiction': 'Fiction'}

df['category'] = df['category'].replace(d)
```