# What is the best way of defining a Pandas df datatypes as a dictionary when there are many columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I often load in csv files using pd.read_csv(), and more often than not they have columns with differing datatypes.

This is fine, as I can pass a dictionary to the dtype argument with all of the columns mapped out with their respective data types.  The problem I'm finding is that, occasionally, these csv files have got a lot of columns, and the resulting dictionary is extremely long.

Often times, the dictionary will look like this:

```
df_dtype = {

             'A' : str,
             'B' : str,
             'C' : int
}
```

But when the df is long, the dictionary starts to look like this:

```
df_dtype = {

             'A' : str,
             'B' : str,
             'C' : int,
             'D' : str,
             'E' : str,
             'F' : int,
             'G' : str,
             'H' : str,
             'I' : int,
             'J' : str,
             'K' : str,
             'L' : int,
             'M' : str,
             'N' : str,
             'O' : int,
             'P' : str,
             'Q' : str,
             'R' : int,
             'S' : str,
             'T' : str,
             'U' : int,
             'V' : str,
             'W' : str,
             'X' : int,
             'Y' : str,
             'Z' : str
}
```

Which is ugly and makes the code less readable.

What is the best practice for doing this?  Should I make the dictionary as a separate file in the directory?  Is there a prettier way to format it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is change format for specify type in key of dict and columns names in lists:

```
d_types = {str: ['A', 'B', 'D'], 
           int: ['C','F'],
           float: ['G']}

#swap key values in dict
#http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674731/2901002
d = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d_types.items() for k in oldv}
print (d)
{'A': <class 'str'>, 'B': <class 'str'>, 'D': <class 'str'>,
 'C': <class 'int'>, 'F': <class 'int'>, 'G': <class 'float'>}
```