# How can I group the rows in one column and name them?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data set as the following:

```
Zipcodes  Population  Precipitation
10             10      100
45             20      200
58             30      300
11             40      400
22             50      500
19             60      600
```

and I want to group some Zipcodes (i.g, 10, 22, 19) and name them "a". My out put will look like:

```
Regions   Population   Precipitation
a             120          1200
k              90           900
```

Comment: there is also define `b` ?

Comment: what is your logic for grouping?

Comment: I need to group all zipcodes in zipcode column based on the regions. Each region has centain number of zipcodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each zipcode are defined in list, e.g. in dictionary:

```
d = {'a':[10, 22, 19],
     'b':[45,58,11]}
#swap key values in dict
#http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674731/2901002
d1 = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d.items() for k in oldv}

df['Zipcodes'] = df['Zipcodes'].map(d1)

df = df.groupby('Zipcodes', as_index=False).sum()
print (df)
  Zipcodes  Population  Precipitation
0        a         120           1200
1        b          90            900
```

Or if need separate values matched in list and all another values:

```
df['Zipcodes'] = np.where(df['Zipcodes'].isin([10, 22, 19]), 'a', 'b')
df = df.groupby('Zipcodes', as_index=False).sum()
print (df)
  Zipcodes  Population  Precipitation
0        a         120           1200
1        b          90            900
```