# How to map a column value in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

In my files one column containing different grades( columns name='Grades).

eg: 91 50K,92 60K,DIESEL,ADBlU etc..

For all these grades I need to categorize them in few grades;

eg`: 91 50K= Petrol`

In my python, how can i do this? Note that i can pass the whole column to the function. but function has to rewrite each row's value with the correct one;

```
def checkgrades(data):
df['Grades']=???
???
```

As per below answers I try;

```
 df_dips=map_dips_grades(df_dips)
df_sales = df_sales.merge(df_dips, left_on=['Site Name', 'Date','GradeNo'],
                              right_on=['Site', 'Dip Time', 'Product'], how='left').fillna(0)



def map_dips_grades(data):

    d1 = {'Diesel': ['DIESEL', 'DIESEL 1'],
          'Unleaded': ['91','91 UNLEADED'],
          'PULP':['95','95 ULP'],
          'PULP98':['98','98 20K'],
          'Vortex Diesel':['DIESEL ULT R'],
          'Adblue':['ADBLU','ADO']}

    d = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d1.items() for k in oldv}

    data['Product'].map(d)
    return data
```

But I get;

```
ValueError: You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

Comment: Does `91 50K,92 60K,DIESEL,ADBlU etc..` represent values in a column (`Grades`)?

Comment: @ernest_k Those are the values comes under column{Grades'). I want to rewrite them with some matching grades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create dictionary of all possible values in `Grades` and then [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
#test all possible unique values
print (df['Grades'].unique())

d = {'91 50K':'Petrol','92 60K':'Petrol','DIESEL':'Diesel',...}

df['Grades'] = df['Grades'].map(d)
```

Another possible dictionary for less typing is dict of lists:

```
d1 = {'Petrol':['91 50K','92 60K'],
      'Diesel':['DIESEL']}

#swap key values in dict
#http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674731/2901002
d = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d1.items() for k in oldv}
print (d)
{'91 50K': 'Petrol', '92 60K': 'Petrol', 'DIESEL': 'Diesel'}

df['Grades'] = df['Grades'].map(d)
```

Comment: I used as you mentioned;  I provided my new code block in my question Can you check why I get that error?

Comment: Earlier I was able to merge without issue. This issue caused by new def map_dips_grades(data): method

Comment: @Ratha - If use `data['Product'] = data['Product'].map(d)` instead `data['Product'].map(d)` it working?

Comment: @Ratha - But error means there are different dtypes, what return `print(df_sales[['Site Name', 'Date','GradeNo']].dtypes)` and `print(df_dips[['Site', 'Dip Time', 'Product']].dtypes)` ?

Comment: Thanks You are right ..They are different dtypes, object and int..Ill check further

Comment: @Ratha - yes, mabe is necessary `df['col'].astype(str)`

Comment: Thanks looks..finally I get nothing in my grades column..after merge..Ill check further..looks the way I pass dataframe to the function and returning it is not working

Comment: @Ratha - One idea - what return `print (df['Grades'].tolist())` ? Maybe some whitespaces? Maybe possible see it in `print (df['Grades'].unique())` too.

Comment: Thanks for your qucik answers it works fine..datatype was the issue..i changed that in the middle.mapping works

Answer (score 2):

You can try using a dictionary along with the map() function. Something like this:

```
dict = {'91 50K': 'Petrol', .........}
df['Grades'] = df['Grades'].map(dict)
```

Comment: Never use `dict`  for variable name in python, because `builtins` (python code word)

Comment: I didn't know this and I used 'dict' quite often. But i shall not use it anymore