# How can I add the values of list to column value using apply function and lambda function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, lambda, apply

I want to add the values in column from lists value using apply function and lambda function

I already tried to use 'for' but it spent lots of time because there are many rows (over 60,000).

for example
if 'connection_type' is 'snmpgetattack', 'attack_type' has to be 'R2L'.

[image]

```py
dos = ['udpstorm', 'apache2', 'mailbomb', 'back', 'neptune', 'land',
       'smurf', 'teardrop', 'processtable', 'pod']


probe = ['satan', 'nmap', 'portsweep', 'mscan', 'ipsweep', 'saint']


r2l = ['httptunnel', 'ftp_write', 'worm', 'imap', 'xlock', 'multihop',
       'warezmaster', 'named', 'snmpguess', 'phf', 'snmpgetattack',
       'xsnoop', 'guess_password', 'sendmail']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create dictionary of list from your lists, swap values and use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with removed last `.` by [`Series.str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html):

**Notice**:

If value not exist in any list, `map` function return mising value `NaN`. E.g
 in sample data for `normal.` value, because no `normal` in lists.

```
d1 = {'dos':dos,'probe':probe,'r2l':r2l}

#swap key values in dict
#http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674731/2901002
d = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d1.items() for k in oldv}

df['attack_type'] = df['connection_type'].str.rstrip('.').map(d)
```

**Detail**:

```
print (d)
{'udpstorm': 'dos', 'apache2': 'dos', 'mailbomb': 'dos', 'back': 'dos', 'neptune': 'dos', 'land': 'dos', 'smurf': 'dos', 'teardrop': 'dos', 'processtable': 'dos', 'pod': 'dos', 'satan': 'probe', 'nmap': 'probe', 'portsweep': 'probe', 'mscan': 'probe', 'ipsweep': 'probe', 'saint': 'probe', 'httptunnel': 'r2l', 'ftp_write': 'r2l', 'worm': 'r2l', 'imap': 'r2l', 'xlock': 'r2l', 'multihop': 'r2l', 'warezmaster': 'r2l', 'named': 'r2l', 'snmpguess': 'r2l', 'phf': 'r2l', 'snmpgetattack': 'r2l', 'xsnoop': 'r2l', 'guess_password': 'r2l', 'sendmail': 'r2l'}
```

Comment: Thanks! But it didn't work. In DataFrame there are just 'Nan'. Like below. ![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/42408554/65854566-f74b8800-e397-11e9-9577-c211a085f62e.png)

Comment: @YoungdongKim - There is always `.` to end of each value in `connection_type` ?

Comment: @YoungdongKim - if yes, try remove it by `df['attack_type'] = df['connection_type'].str.rstrip('.').map(d)`

Comment: OMG, I missed '.' to end of each value...I did it! Thanks!