# Map dict keys to new column in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently mapping dict keys to a column based values in a separate column. I'm using the values in `Code` to match the values in a dict and copying the keys to a separate column. So the new column will contain numbers `1,2,3`.

This works fine except for the multiple code values at the same timestamp. 
I only want to have one mapped value for each unique timestamp.

If there are multiple value at the same timestamp but the mapped number will be the same `(A,B)`, then just take the first value. I can use `.drop_duplicates` for this.

**However, If the mapped numbers are different at the same time point, I want to drop `2` and select `1`. `.drop_duplicates` will only work if `1` if listed before `2` but not vice versa**

```py
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import process

df = pd.DataFrame({   
        'Time' : ['2019-08-02 09:50:10.1','2019-08-02 09:50:10.1','2019-08-02 09:50:10.2','2019-08-02 09:50:10.3','2019-08-02 09:50:10.4','2019-08-02 09:50:10.4','2019-08-02 09:50:10.5','2019-08-02 09:50:10.5','2019-08-02 09:50:10.6','2019-08-02 09:50:10.6'],
        'Code' : ['A','C','X','Y','A','B','X','A','Z','L'],                                   
        })

# Dictionary that contains how to map numbers
hdict = {'1' : ['A', 'B'],

    '2' : ['X','Y','Z'],

    '3' : ['D']}

def hColumn(df):

    # Construct a dataframe from the helper dictionary
    df1 = pd.DataFrame([*hdict.values()], index = hdict.keys()).T.melt().dropna()   
    # Get relevant matches using the library.
    m = df['Code'].apply(lambda x: process.extract(x, df1.value)[0])
    # Concat the matches with original df
    df2 = pd.concat([df, m[m.apply(lambda x: x[1]>80)].apply(lambda x: x[0])], axis=1)
    df2.columns = [*df.columns, 'matches']
    # After merge it with df1
    df2 = df2.merge(df1, left_on='matches', right_on='value', how='left')
    # Drop columns that are not required and rename.
    df2 = df2.drop(['matches','value'],1).rename(columns={'variable':'H'})
    # Drop unwanted rows
    df2 = df2.mask(df2['H'].isna())
    df2 = df2.dropna(subset = ['H'])

    return df2

df = hColumn(df)
```

Intended Output:

```
                    Time Code  H
0  2019-08-02 09:50:10.1    A  1
1  2019-08-02 09:50:10.2    X  2
2  2019-08-02 09:50:10.3    Y  2
3  2019-08-02 09:50:10.4    A  1
4  2019-08-02 09:50:10.5    A  1
5  2019-08-02 09:50:10.6    Z  2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = df.drop_duplicates('Time')
```

If possible, here is another solution - it match values by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
#swap key values in dict
#http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674731/2901002
d = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in hdict.items() for k in oldv}
df["H"] = df['Code'].map(d)
df = df.dropna(subset=['H']).drop_duplicates('Time')
print (df)
                    Time Code  H
0  2019-08-02 09:50:10.1    A  1
2  2019-08-02 09:50:10.2    X  2
3  2019-08-02 09:50:10.3    Y  2
4  2019-08-02 09:50:10.4    A  1
6  2019-08-02 09:50:10.5    X  2
8  2019-08-02 09:50:10.6    Z  2
```

Comment: This only works well for dropping same numbers. But when 1 and 2 are mapped at the same time `(09:50:10.5)` I want to drop `2` and keep `1`.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would "reverse" you dictionary, it will very simplify all next actions, my solution is as follows, please let me know if it helped and feel free to ask questions:

```
import pandas as pd

# start data:
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Time': ['2019-08-02 09:50:10.1', '2019-08-02 09:50:10.1', '2019-08-02 09:50:10.2',
                 '2019-08-02 09:50:10.3', '2019-08-02 09:50:10.4', '2019-08-02 09:50:10.4',
                 '2019-08-02 09:50:10.5', '2019-08-02 09:50:10.5',
                 '2019-08-02 09:50:10.6', '2019-08-02 09:50:10.6'],
        'Code': ['A', 'C', 'X', 'Y', 'A', 'B', 'X', 'A', 'Z', 'L'],
        })

#start data:
hdict = {'1': ['A', 'B'],
         '2': ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
         '3': ['D']
         }

# "reverse dictionary"
reversed_hdict = {}
for k, v in hdict.items():
    for element in v:
        reversed_hdict[element] = k

print(reversed_hdict) # what dictionary we have now

# add new column by apply method:
df["new_column"] = df['Code'].apply(lambda x: reversed_hdict.get(x))

# check what we have now
print(df)

# print without None rows
print(df.dropna())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from flashtext import KeywordProcessor
kp = KeywordProcessor()
kp.add_keywords_from_dict(hdict)

df['H'] = df['Code'].apply(lambda x : kp.extract_keywords(x))

df['H'] = df['H'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[0]) if x else pd.Series())
df.dropna(inplace = True)
df
```

[image]