# Multi header and sub header in existing dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have data like below table:

```
EMP_code     Emp_Name     M_code M_name
123           A           234     E
124           B           235     F
125           C           236     G 
126           D           237     H
```

I need add header like :

```
      EMP_details           M_details   
EMP_code     Emp_Name     M_code M_name
123           A           234     E
124           B           235     F
125           C           236     G 
126           D           237     H
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Create dictionary of all first level values and after swapping use [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html):

```
d = {'EMP_details':['EMP_code','Emp_Name'], 'M_details':['M_code','M_name']}

#swap key values in dict
#http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674731/2901002
d1 = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d.items() for k in oldv}
print (d1)
{'EMP_code': 'EMP_details', 'Emp_Name': 'EMP_details', 
 'M_code': 'M_details', 'M_name': 'M_details'}

df.columns = [df.columns.map(d1.get), df.columns]
print (df)
  EMP_details          M_details       
     EMP_code Emp_Name    M_code M_name
0         123        A       234      E
1         124        B       235      F
2         125        C       236      G
3         126        D       237      H
```

Comment: EMP_details is repeating for emp_code and emp_name...i need as marge cell for both

Comment: @SandeepGupta - Not understand, can you explian more?

Comment: Emp_details is showing two times . i.e. on both column for emp_code and emp_name..while i need this only one time with marge cells for below columns.       it showing as  :-
EMP_details  EMP_details     M_details    M_details   
EMP_code     Emp_Name     M_code M_name
123           A           234     E
124           B           235     F
125           C           236     G 
126           D           237     H

Comment: @SandeepGupta - `Emp_details is showing two times` - it is expected, because MultiIndex. But if write dataframe to excel get only one `Emp_details`