# Pandas series replace values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a pandas series with values below:

```
Bachelors Degree         639
Diploma                  291
O - Level                264
Masters Degree           149
Certificate              126
A - Level                 69
PGD                       40
Bachelors Degree          28
A-Level                   20
O-Level                   15
Masters                   10
Bachelors                  6
diploma                    5
certificate                5
Ph.D                       4
A- Level                   2
Post Graduate Diploma      1
Msc Environment            1
BBA                        1
O- Level                   1
Masters                    1
PhD                        1
```

I got data from excel.

I want to use pandas to do the data cleaning by say replacing all cases which has Masters with Master's degree (i can do it in excel but i am learning pandas).

I have tried

```
mapp={"Bachelor's Degree":["Bachelors Degree","Bachelors","BBA","Bachelors Degree"],
      "Ordinary Diploma":"diploma",
      "Ordinary Level":["O - Level","O-Level","O- Level"],
      "Master's Degree":["Masters Degree","Masters","Msc Environment","Masters"],
      "Certificate":"certificate",
      "Advanced Level":["A - Level","A-Level","- Level"],
      "Post Graduate Diploma":["Post Graduate Diploma","PGD"],
      "PHD":["Ph.D","PhD"]    
     }
df['EDUCATION_LEVEL']=df['EDUCATION_LEVEL'].map(mapp)
```

The results are returned only for the Certificate key which has only one value.

It seems i cant use a list as values for a dictionary key.

Any suggestion on how to replace the values will be highly appreciated.
Ronald
This is how actual data appear in the excel column.
[image]

I have added an image of how data is in the column.
The challenge is how replace the various varriations of say "Masters Degree".

Answer (score 0):

One idea is convert one element values to one element lists like `"diploma"` to `["diploma"]`:

```
mapp1={"Bachelor's Degree":["Bachelors Degree","Bachelors","BBA","Bachelors Degree"],
      "Ordinary Diploma":["diploma"],
      "Ordinary Level":["O - Level","O-Level","O- Level"],
      "Master's Degree":["Masters Degree","Masters","Msc Environment","Masters"],
      "Certificate":["certificate"],
      "Advanced Level":["A - Level","A-Level","- Level"],
      "Post Graduate Diploma":["Post Graduate Diploma","PGD"],
      "PHD":["Ph.D","PhD"]    
     }
```

---

```
#swap key values in dict
#http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674731/2901002
d = {k.lower(): oldk for oldk, oldv in mapp1.items() for k in oldv}
df['EDUCATION_LEVEL']=df['EDUCATION_LEVEL'].str.lower().map(d)
print (df)
          EDUCATION_LEVEL  VAL
0       Bachelor's Degree  639
1        Ordinary Diploma  291
2          Ordinary Level  264
3         Master's Degree  149
4             Certificate  126
5          Advanced Level   69
6   Post Graduate Diploma   40
7       Bachelor's Degree   28
8          Advanced Level   20
9          Ordinary Level   15
10        Master's Degree   10
11      Bachelor's Degree    6
12       Ordinary Diploma    5
13            Certificate    5
14                    PHD    4
15                    NaN    2
16  Post Graduate Diploma    1
17        Master's Degree    1
18      Bachelor's Degree    1
19         Ordinary Level    1
20        Master's Degree    1
21                    PHD    1
```

If not possible then use:

```
d = {}
for k, v in mapp.items():
    if isinstance(v, list):
        for x in v:
            d[x.lower()] = k
    else:
        d[v.lower()] = k


df['EDUCATION_LEVEL']=df['EDUCATION_LEVEL'].str.lower().map(d)
print (df)
          EDUCATION_LEVEL  VAL
0       Bachelor's Degree  639
1        Ordinary Diploma  291
2          Ordinary Level  264
3         Master's Degree  149
4             Certificate  126
5          Advanced Level   69
6   Post Graduate Diploma   40
7       Bachelor's Degree   28
8          Advanced Level   20
9          Ordinary Level   15
10        Master's Degree   10
11      Bachelor's Degree    6
12       Ordinary Diploma    5
13            Certificate    5
14                    PHD    4
15                    NaN    2
16  Post Graduate Diploma    1
17        Master's Degree    1
18      Bachelor's Degree    1
19         Ordinary Level    1
20        Master's Degree    1
21                    PHD    1
```

Comment: I got Nan values using this method.

Answer (score 0):

First make a slight change to your mapp dict by setting all the values as list:

```
mapp={"Bachelor's Degree":["Bachelors Degree","Bachelors","BBA","Bachelors Degree"],
      "Ordinary Diploma":["diploma"],
      "Ordinary Level":["O - Level","O-Level","O- Level"],
      "Master's Degree":["Masters Degree","Masters","Msc Environment","Masters"],
      "Certificate":["certificate"],
      "Advanced Level":["A - Level","A-Level","- Level"],
      "Post Graduate Diploma":["Post Graduate Diploma","PGD"],
      "PHD":["Ph.D","PhD"]    
     }

mapp_new = [{l:k for l in v} for k,v in mapp.items()]
mapp_new = {k.lower(): v for d in mapp_new for k, v in d.items()}
df.EDUCATION_LEVEL.apply(lambda x: mapp_new.get(x.lower(), x))


0         Bachelor's Degree
1          Ordinary Diploma
2            Ordinary Level
3           Master's Degree
4               Certificate
5            Advanced Level
6     Post Graduate Diploma
7         Bachelor's Degree
8            Advanced Level
9            Ordinary Level
10          Master's Degree
11        Bachelor's Degree
12         Ordinary Diploma
13              Certificate
14                      PHD
15                 A- Level
16    Post Graduate Diploma
17          Master's Degree
18        Bachelor's Degree
19           Ordinary Level
20          Master's Degree
21                      PHD
```

Comment: I have got Nan values using this method