# If column contain string from array of strings create new column with

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that look like this

```
     Col1     Col2    
0     22     Apple
1     43     Carrot 
2     54     Orange
3     74     Spinach
4     14     Cucumber
```

And I need to add new column with the category "Fruit" , "Vegetable" or "Leaf"
I created a list for each category

```
Fru = {'Apple','Orange', 'Grape', 'Blueberry', 'Strawberry'}
Veg = {'Cucumber','Carrot','Broccoli', 'Onion'}
Leaf = {'Lettuce', 'Kale', 'Spinach'}
```

And the result should look like this

```
    Col1      Col2     Category 
0     22     Apple      Fruit
1     43     Carrot     Vegetable 
2     54     Orange     Fruit
3     74     Spinach    Leaf
4     14     Cucumber   Vegetable
```

I tried **np.where**  and **contains** yet both functions give: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with new dictionary `d1`:

```
Fru = {'Apple','Orange', 'Grape', 'Blueberry', 'Strawberry'}
Veg = {'Cucumber','Carrot','Broccoli', 'Onion'}
Leaf = {'Lettuce', 'Kale', 'Spinach'}

d = {'Fruit':Fru, 'Vegetable':Veg,'Leaf':Leaf}

#swap key values in dict
#http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674731/2901002
d1 = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d.items() for k in oldv}
print (d1)

df['Category'] = df['Col2'].map(d1)
print (df)
   Col1      Col2   Category
0    22     Apple      Fruit
1    43    Carrot  Vegetable
2    54    Orange      Fruit
3    74   Spinach       Leaf
4    14  Cucumber  Vegetable
```

Or use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
df['Category'] = np.select([df['Col2'].isin(Fru),df['Col2'].isin(Veg),df['Col2'].isin(Leaf)],
                           ['Fruit','Vegetable','Leaf'])
print (df)

   Col1      Col2   Category
0    22     Apple      Fruit
1    43    Carrot  Vegetable
2    54    Orange      Fruit
3    74   Spinach       Leaf
4    14  Cucumber  Vegetable
```

Comment: These are the times for our answers! Celius: 0.000997304916381836, Jezrael: 0.0009975433349609375  Go 500k! +3

Comment: @CeliusStingher - thank you, but what is number of rows for test?

Comment: The sample OP gives.

Comment: @CeliusStingher - Better is 1k, 10k, 100k rows because in small data sometimes timings are different like in bigger

Comment: I tested for 1k, 10k, 100k  and they are the virtually the same performance wise

Comment: It's not as flexible or robust... but in this case given it's a low number of categories... a direct `d1 = {**dict.fromkeys(Fru, 'Fruit'), **dict.fromkeys(Veg, 'Vegetable'), **dict.fromkeys(Leaf, 'Leaf')}` is also an option. Some may find it more obvious as to what it's doing reading wise... just throwing it out there.

Comment: the first answer worked very well although I do not get how it works. can you explain the logic of it. I mean in couple of words so I can read more about it

Comment: What Jezrael is doing in the first answer is basically "inverting"/ swapping the dictionary keys with their values. So, instead of `{"Fruit":["Apple","Orange","Banana"]}` -> into -> `{"Apple":"Fruit","Orange":"Fruit","Banana","Fruit"}` that way we can use `map`.

Comment: @CeliusStingher - yes, but swapping is created dynamically

Comment: Yes, of course it is dynamic, that's the great thing about the answer

Answer (score 2):

That's because you did not create a list, you created a set as your error shows. You can try making the set a list as the argument for the `.isin()`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[22,43,54,74,14],'Col2':['Apple','Carrot','Orange','Spinach','Cucumber']})

Fru = {'Apple','Orange', 'Grape', 'Blueberry', 'Strawberry'}
Veg = {'Cucumber','Carrot','Broccoli', 'Onion'}
Leaf = {'Lettuce', 'Kale', 'Spinach'}

df['Category'] = np.where(df['Col2'].isin(Fru),'Fruit',
  np.where(df['Col2'].isin(Veg),'Vegetable',
  np.where(df['Col2'].isin(Leaf),'Leaf')))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Col1      Col2   Category
0    22     Apple      Fruit
1    43    Carrot  Vegetable
2    54    Orange      Fruit
3    74   Spinach       Leaf
4    14  Cucumber  Vegetable
```

Comment: Yes, I assume there is no other possibility, but I will edit to contemplate it, thanks.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I just tested it and `list()` is not neccessary.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach you can try with a `for loop`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [22,43,54,74,14], 'Col2': ['Apple','Carrot','Orange','Spinach','Cucumber']})

Fruit = ['Apple','Orange', 'Grape', 'Blueberry', 'Strawberry']
Vegetable = ['Cucumber','Carrot','Broccoli', 'Onion']
Leaf = ['Lettuce', 'Kale', 'Spinach']

mylist = []
for i in df['Col2']:
    if i in Fruit:
        mylist.append('Fruit')
    elif i in Vegetable:
        mylist.append('Vegetable')
    elif i in Leaf:
        mylist.append('Leaf')

df['Category'] = mylist

print(df)
   Col1      Col2   Category
0    22     Apple      Fruit
1    43    Carrot  Vegetable
2    54    Orange      Fruit
3    74   Spinach       Leaf
4    14  Cucumber  Vegetable
```

Comment: I like your approach and I tried it but with contain (that was my mistake) but the original data has more 200 item in 15 category which would not be efficient using this way

Comment: Yes, other solutions by experts like jezrael and Celius Stingher are more efficient, I wanted to ensure that I post my solution as I spent some time to write this code :)