# How to "reverse-map" keys of a dictionary to a row, if one in the list of values matches in the row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

there is this list with among others the columns, year and criterion. There also is a dictionary of labels (key) each with a list of criteria (value). 
I would like to add a label each row in which the criterion matches one entry in the list of values.

As an example:

```
import pandas as pd 

labels_dict = {'label_1': [1,2],
         'label_2': [4,6]}

df = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2014,2014,2015,2015,2016,2016], 
                   'criterion':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})

>>> print(df)
   year  criterion
0  2014          1
1  2014          2
2  2015          3
3  2015          4
4  2016          5
5  2016          6


target_labels = pd.DataFrame({'labels': ['label_1', 'label_1', pd.NaT, 'label_2', pd.NaT, 'label_2']})

target_df = pd.concat([df, target_labels], axis=1)

>>> print(target_df)
   year  criterion   labels
0  2014          1  label_1
1  2014          2  label_1
2  2015          3      NaT
3  2015          4  label_2
4  2016          5      NaT
5  2016          6  label_2
```

Some notes:

The dictionary of labels is the best idea I could come up with, but since I create it manually, I could use a different object.

I unsucessfully tried (each loop overwrites the entire column):

```
for key in labels_dict.keys():
    df['labels'] = df.loc[df['criterion'].isin(labels_dict[key]), :]['year'].apply(lambda x: key)
```

Switching key and value in `labels_dict` does not work, since lists are unhashable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to create an reverse dictionary and map:

```
reverse_label = {x:k for k,v in labels_dict.items() for x in v}

df['labels'] = df['criterion'].map(reverse_label)
```

Output:

```
   year  criterion   labels
0  2014          1  label_1
1  2014          2  label_1
2  2015          3      NaN
3  2015          4  label_2
4  2016          5      NaN
5  2016          6  label_2
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with dictionary:

```
#swap key values in dict
#http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674731/2901002
d = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in labels_dict.items() for k in oldv}
df['labels'] = df['criterion'].map(d)
print(df)
   year  criterion   labels
0  2014          1  label_1
1  2014          2  label_1
2  2015          3      NaN
3  2015          4  label_2
4  2016          5      NaN
5  2016          6  label_2
```

Answer (score 1):

New way after 0.25 `explode`

```
s=pd.Series(labels_dict).explode()
df['labels']=df.criterion.map(dict(zip(s,s.index)))
df
Out[137]: 
   year  criterion   labels
0  2014          1  label_1
1  2014          2  label_1
2  2015          3      NaN
3  2015          4  label_2
4  2016          5      NaN
5  2016          6  label_2
```