# Put keys of dictionary in column of DataFrame when the value of the key is in other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

This is the `DataFrame`:

```
d_vals ={'vals': [i for i in range(1, 6)]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d_vals)
df

    vals
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
```

And this the `dictionary`:

```
d_groups = {
    'a': [1, 2],
    'b': [3, 5],
    'c': [4]
}
```

The point is to get a new column `groups` with the key of the `dictionary` when the value of the column `vals` is in the values of the key.

The final `DataFrame` should be as follows:

```
    vals    groups
0   1       a
1   2       a
2   3       b
3   4       c
4   5       b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with flattening dictionary to new one:

```
#swap key values in dict
#http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674731/2901002
d = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d_groups.items() for k in oldv}

df['groups'] = df['vals'].map(d)
print (df)
   vals groups
0     1      a
1     2      a
2     3      b
3     4      c
4     5      b
```