# How to add a specific word to a new column when it is a value in a list within a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, contains

supposed my data set

```
name what
A    apple[red]
B    cucumber[green]
C    dog
C    orange
D    banana
D    monkey
E    cat
F    carrot
.
.
```

I want to create and specify a list, and if the column contains a value contained in that list, I want to make the specified value a new column.

list value

```
fruit = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
animal = ['dog', 'monkey', 'cat']
vegetable = ['cucumber', 'carrot']
```

result what I want

```
name what     class
A    apple    fruit
B    cucumber vegetable
C    dog      animal
C    orange   fruit
D    banana   fruit
D    monkey   animal
E    cat      animal
F    carrot   vegetable
```

**List values and column values do not 'match' and must be contained.**

thank you for reading.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Anwarvic df1 = df['column anme'].str.contains("|".join(listname)) ,, It couldn't specify multiple lists, and couldn't say the words I specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with dictionary created from lists and swapped keys with values with flattening:

```
fruit = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
animal = ['dog', 'monkey', 'cat']
vegetable = ['cucumber', 'carrot']

d = {'fruit':fruit, 'animal':animal,'vegetable':vegetable}
#http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674731/2901002
d1 = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d.items() for k in oldv}
```

Loop alternative of dictionary comprehension:

```
d1 = {}
for oldk, oldv in d.items():
    for k in oldv:
        d1[k] = oldk
```

And then:

```
df['class'] = df['what'].map(d1)
#if need values before first [
#df['class'] = df['what'].str.split('[').str[0].map(d1)
print (df)
  name      what      class
0    A     apple      fruit
1    B  cucumber  vegetable
2    C       dog     animal
3    C    orange      fruit
4    D    banana      fruit
5    D    monkey     animal
6    E       cat     animal
7    F    carrot  vegetable
```

EDIT: For match by subtrings you can loop by dictionary `d`, check matching by [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for mask and set new values:

```
d = {'fruit':fruit, 'animal':animal,'vegetable':vegetable}

for k, v in d.items():
    mask = df['what'].str.contains('|'.join(v))
    df.loc[mask, 'class'] = k
print (df)
  name             what      class
0    A       apple[red]      fruit
1    B  cucumber[green]  vegetable
2    C              dog     animal
3    C           orange      fruit
4    D           banana      fruit
5    D           monkey     animal
6    E              cat     animal
7    F           carrot  vegetable
```

If possible multiple words is possible use words boundaries:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in v)
    df.loc[ df['what'].str.contains(pat), 'class'] = k
print (df)
  name             what      class
0    A       apple[red]      fruit
1    B  cucumber[green]  vegetable
2    C              dog     animal
3    C           orange      fruit
4    D           banana      fruit
5    D           monkey     animal
6    E              cat     animal
7    F           carrot  vegetable
```

Comment: I was typing up the same answer but I can't beat an AI that answers pandas questions.

Comment: @ybin - sure, it is used for iterate by dictonary `d`, `oldk` and `oldv` means original keys and original values.

Comment: jezrael, I just made a change, but what and list values do not match, and there are other values like apple [red] above, so can the value of that list be a condition of 'contain' rather than 'match'?

Comment: All of my actual datasets are made up of multiple words. Sorry for the hassle,,

Comment: thank you! Can I make it search without distinguishing between uppercase and lowercase letters? then I using `If possible multiple words is possible use words boundaries:?`

Comment: @ybin - yes, it is exacly what I means last paragraph.

Comment: @jezrael oh I solved using `list = [f"(?i){re.escape(k)}" for k in list]` thank you very much !