# Creating new column by mapping existing column

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe column let's say **df['towns']**

```
Apple
banana
cigor
delmon
```

and dictionary

```
cities = {
     'x':[Apple,Banana],
     'y':[Cigor,Zoor,Elk],
     'z':[Delmon,Foo]
}
```

I want to create new column as **df['city']** and label each row according to my dictionary. What is the proper way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), but first change dictionary with convert to lowercase:

```
#swap key values in dict
#http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674731/2901002

d = {k.lower() : oldk for oldk, oldv in cities.items() for k in oldv}

df1['city'] = df1['towns'].str.lower().map(d)
print (df1)
    towns city
0   Apple    x
1  banana    x
2   cigor    y
3  delmon    z
```

Or if need convert values to capitalize words:

```
d = {k : oldk for oldk, oldv in cities.items() for k in oldv}
#first letter first word
df1['city'] = df1['towns'].str.title().map(d)
#first letter all words
#df1['city'] = df1['towns'].str.capitalize().map(d)
```

Comment: In case I have town with upper case, how to check? I cannot add k.lower apperantly :/

Comment: @Fragrance - You cannot use `d = {k.lower(): oldk for oldk, oldv in cities.items() for k in oldv}` ?