# Python Pandas: How do I create a column given a condition based on another column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given the following dataframe:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, "BURGLARY"], [2, "PETIT LARCENY"], [3, "DANGEROUS DRUGS"], [4, "LOITERING FOR DRUG PURPOSES"], [5, "DANGEROUS WEAPONS"]],
      columns = ['id','ofns_desc']
)
```

[image]

I want to add a new column that simplifies the description in the `ofns_desc` column. I did the following:

```
THEFT = ["BURGLARY", "PETIT LARCENY"]
df_test.loc[df_test.ofns_desc.isin(THEFT), 'category'] = "THEFT"

DRUGS = ["DANGEROUS DRUGS", "LOITERING FOR DRUG PURPOSES"]
df_test.loc[df_test.ofns_desc.isin(DRUGS), 'category'] = "DRUGS"
```

Up to this point, the code above works:

[image]

But when I try to create an `"OTHER"` value for the `category` column, every value in the `category` column gets overwritten:

```
ALL_CAT = [THEFT, DRUGS]
df_test.loc[~df_test.ofns_desc.isin(ALL_CAT), 'category'] = "OTHER"
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is you test nested lists, so all values failed, you need join lists by `+` instead pass to `[]` like change:

```
ALL_CAT = [THEFT, DRUGS]
```

to:

```
ALL_CAT = THEFT + DRUGS
```

Another idea is create dictionaries and [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), last replace missing values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
THEFT = ["BURGLARY", "PETIT LARCENY"]
DRUGS = ["DANGEROUS DRUGS", "LOITERING FOR DRUG PURPOSES"]
d = {"THEFT":THEFT, 'DRUGS':DRUGS}

#swap key values in dict
#http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674731/2901002
d1 = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d.items() for k in oldv}
print (d1)
{'BURGLARY': 'THEFT', 'PETIT LARCENY': 'THEFT',
 'DANGEROUS DRUGS': 'DRUGS', 'LOITERING FOR DRUG PURPOSES': 'DRUGS'}

df_test['category'] = df_test['ofns_desc'].map(d1).fillna("OTHER")
print (df_test)
   id                    ofns_desc category
0   1                     BURGLARY    THEFT
1   2                PETIT LARCENY    THEFT
2   3              DANGEROUS DRUGS    DRUGS
3   4  LOITERING FOR DRUG PURPOSES    DRUGS
4   5            DANGEROUS WEAPONS    OTHER
```

Answer (score 4):

It's better to use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for this. Its much performant:

```
In [2555]: import numpy as np

In [2556]: THEFT = ["BURGLARY", "PETIT LARCENY"]

In [2557]: DRUGS = ["DANGEROUS DRUGS", "LOITERING FOR DRUG PURPOSES"]

In [2558]: conditions = [df_test.ofns_desc.isin(THEFT), df_test.ofns_desc.isin(DRUGS)]

In [2559]: choices = ['THEFT', 'DRUGS']

In [2564]: df_test['category'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='OTHER')

In [2565]: df_test
Out[2565]: 
   id                    ofns_desc category
0   1                     BURGLARY    THEFT
1   2                PETIT LARCENY    THEFT
2   3              DANGEROUS DRUGS    DRUGS
3   4  LOITERING FOR DRUG PURPOSES    DRUGS
4   5            DANGEROUS WEAPONS    OTHER
```

Comment: yop, if few values yes, if many then map is better choice here.

Answer (score 2):

Instead fill the NaN values?

```
df_test['category'] = df_test['category'].fillna("OTHER")
```