# Add a part of string in a column based on the values of another column (Python Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe like this

```
Anno | Mese
___________
2018 | Gennaio
2019 | Febbraio
2020 | Aprile
```

If the values of Mese are: Gennaio, Febbraio, Marzo --> i want Anno to be year_Q1
If the values of Mese are: Aprile, Maggio, Giugno, --> i want Anno to be year_Q2
If the values of Mese are: Luglio, Agosto, Settembre,  --> i want Anno to be year_Q3
If the values of Mese are: Ottobre, Novembre, Dicembre --> i want Anno to be year_Q4

My expected output is:

```
Anno | Mese
___________
2018_Q1 | Gennaio
2019_Q1 | Febbraio
2020_Q2 | Aprile
```

How can I do it in an efficient way in Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary with chnged dictionary and add to `anno` column:

```
d = {'Q1': ['Gennaio', 'Febbraio', 'Marzo'],
     'Q2': ['Aprile', 'Maggio', 'Giugno'],
     'Q3': ['Luglio', 'Agosto', 'Settembre'],
     'Q4': ['Ottobre', 'Novembre', 'Dicembre']}

#http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674731/2901002
d1 = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d.items() for k in oldv}

df['Anno'] = df['Anno'].astype(str) + '_' + df['Mese'].map(d1)
print (df)
      Anno      Mese
0  2018_Q1   Gennaio
1  2019_Q1  Febbraio
2  2020_Q2    Aprile
```