# Replace multiple values in cell in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dictionary

I have a dataframe `frame` which looks like this

```
     place           type
0   sometown    α－ＲＸⅡ;α－Ｒ
1   sometown    NYC-iA-SV2;NX-SH
```

where column `type` has a values delimited with `;`

I also have a dictionary `categories_dict` which looks like this

```py
{'phone': ['NX2-S',
  'NX2-M',
  'NX2-S',
  'NX2-M',
  'NX2-L',
  'NYC-iA'
  ...
 ],
'UTM': ['α－ＲＸⅡ',
   'α－Ｒ',
   ...]
}
```

which contains some category as `key` and type as `value`.

I would like to replace all values (split by `;`) from dataframe `frame` column `type` by `key` from `categories_dict` based on matched `value`.

So I want to have something like this

```py
     place           type
0   sometown    (UTM, UTM)
1   sometown    (phone, phone)
```

I'm doing it this way, but it really doesn't looks nice...

I would like to know, if there is a better way to do this...

```py
for index, row in frame.iterrows(): # all rows from df
    data = row[1].split(";") # get row values - splitting
    for one_data in data: # loop all values of row
        for key, val in categories_dict.items():
            if one_data in val:
                data.remove(one_data)
                data.append(key)
```

Comment: Your `type` column has values like `α－ＲＸⅡ` which I cannot find in the `dict`. Please provide the correct dict.

Comment: that `dict` has a lot of values, so I had to shorten that. Its just for explanation purposes. But okay, I'm gonna edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first swap keys with lists (flatten) dictionary and then in nested list comprehension get values if match:

```
#http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674731/2901002
d = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in categories_dict.items() for k in oldv}
 
df['type'] = df['type'].apply(lambda x: tuple([d[y] for y in x.split(';') if y in d]))
print (df)
      place            type
0  sometown      (UTM, UTM)
1  sometown  (phone, phone)
```

If original data is not matching are added to tuple, it working because `dict.get` function has second argument for return value if no match - so is used returned original:

```
print (df)
      place                    type
0  sometown  α－ＲＸⅡ;α－Ｒ;another data
1  sometown        NYC-iA-SV2;NX-SH

#http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674731/2901002
d = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in categories_dict.items() for k in oldv}
 
df['type'] = df['type'].apply(lambda x: tuple([d.get(y, y) for y in x.split(';')]))
print (df)
      place                      type
0  sometown  (UTM, UTM, another data)
1  sometown            (phone, phone)
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, I executed that, but getting `TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not float` in  `f = lambda ...`

Comment: @MarcelKopera - how working if change `x.split(';')` to `str(x).split(';')` ?

Comment: @MarcelKopera - If test first 5 rows on Dataframe only, same error?

Comment: tried it this way `frame['紐付き実績_機種カテゴリ名'][:5].apply(f)` same error

Comment: @MarcelKopera - What is `print(frame['紐付き実績_機種カテゴリ名'][:5].tolist())` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227870/discussion-between-jezrael-and-marcel-kopera).

Comment: sorrry, I used the originalcolumn name in japanese.. The output is
['α－ＲＸⅡ;', 'NYC-iA-SV2;NX-SH;', 'α－ＲＸⅡ;GX-S;', 'AX(D)', 'NYC-iZ20V2E(IP)']

Answer (score 2):

try [pandas.DataFrame.explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to Transform each element of a list-like to a row, and handle it. then use `groupby` with `agg(tuple)` get the result.

sample data:

```
data = [{'place': 'sometown', 'type': 'α－ＲＸⅡ;α－Ｒ'},
 {'place': 'sometown', 'type': 'NYC-iA-SV2;NX-SH'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
category_dict = {'phone': ['NYC-iA-SV2', 'NX-SH', 'NX2-S', 'NX2-M', 'NX2-L', 'NYC-iA'],
 'UTM': ['α－ＲＸⅡ', 'α－Ｒ']}
```

---

process:

```
# flatten the category_dict 
obj_map = pd.Series(category_dict).explode()
obj_dict = dict(zip(obj_map.values, obj_map.index))

    {'NYC-iA-SV2': 'phone',
     'NX-SH': 'phone',
     'NX2-S': 'phone',
     'NX2-M': 'phone',
     'NX2-L': 'phone',
     'NYC-iA': 'phone',
     'α－ＲＸⅡ': 'UTM',
     'α－Ｒ': 'UTM'}

obj_cat = (df['type'].str.split(';')
    .explode()
    .map(obj_dict)
    .groupby(level=0)
    .agg(tuple))

df['obj_cat'] = obj_cat
```

---

output:

```
print(df)
      place              type         obj_cat
0  sometown         α－ＲＸⅡ;α－Ｒ      (UTM, UTM)
1  sometown  NYC-iA-SV2;NX-SH  (phone, phone)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily by creating a new function:

```
def mapping(x):   
    if x in categories_dict['phone']:
        return('phone')
    elif x in categories_dict['UTM']:
        return('UTM')
    else:
        return(i)

df['type'].apply(lambda x:[ mapping(i) for i in x.split(';')]   )


0      [UTM, UTM]
1    [phone, phone]
```