# Use a dictionary to replace words in a sentence

Tags: python

I have created a dictionary that I use to use to bring a variety of words to its base form.

```
dictionary = {'sunny': 'sun', 'banking': 'bank'}

def stemmingWords(sentence, dictionary):
    for word in sentence.split():
        temp = []
        if word in dictionary:
            word = dictionary[word]
            temp.append(word)
    sentence = ' '.join(temp)
    return(sentence)
```

Now if print the separate words it seems to work. However when I insert a whole sentence and I would like an updated version of this sentence something seems to go wrong. For example if I do:

```
sentence = "the sun us shining"
new_sentence = stemmingWords(sentence, dictionary)
print(new_sentence)
```

Gives me "shining". While I am looking "the sunny in shining".

Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Comment: your dictionary would be more useful and efficient if it was as `{ 'sun':'sunny',  'bank' : 'banking'}`

Comment: For the sentence : "the sun is shining"....What is ur expected output?

Comment: @VijayKalmath, the output I expect is "the sunny is shining". So sun should be replaced by sunny... (thats what the dictionary is for)

Answer (score 5):

First, your dictionary is the wrong way round, reverse it

```
dictionary = {'sunny': 'sun', 'banking': 'bank'}
```

a simple way to do it to avoid retyping it would be:

```
dictionary = {v:k for k,v in dictionary.items()}
```

note that if several words match a same word, reverting the dictionary won't work you have to solve the ambiguity first: so manually:

```
dictionary = {'sun', 'sunny': , 'sunn' : 'sunny', 'bank': 'banking'}
```

Then split and rebuild the string using a list comprehension and a `get` access returning the original value if not in the dictionary

```
def stemmingWords(sentence,dictionary):
    return " ".join([dictionary.get(w,w) for w in sentence.split()])

print(stemmingWords("the sun is shining",dictionary))
```

result:

```
the sunny is shining
```

note the deliberate `([])` when using `join`. It's faster to pass explicitly the list comprehension than the generator in that case.

Comment: Very pythonic answer

Comment: Many thanks! However the dictionary should be able to have multiple values per key. So like dictionary['sunny'] = ['sun', 'sunn']. How would you do this?>

Comment: You don't get the principle of a dictionary. key comes first, then the matching value. You write it backwards. Check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

The issues with your functions are the followig:

1. Dictionary key-value are swapped.
   Workaround: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/1031878/4954434
2. The `append()` function by default will append to end of the list.
   Thus position is not taken care properly.
3. `temp` does not have all the words.

The following function should work.

```
def stemmingWords(sentence, dictionary):
    dictionary = dict((v,k) for k,v in dictionary.iteritems())

    splitted = sentence.split()
    for i in range(len(splitted)):
        if splitted[i] in dictionary:
            print splitted[i]
            splitted[i] = dictionary[splitted[i]]
    sentence = ' '.join(splitted)
    return(sentence)
```

While I hope this answer will help newbies, [Jean-François Fabre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41919196/4954434) is far better.