# How to print key from its values in dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have been working on operations of dictionaries .
In the below code, I want to extract the **key** from the value.
How to do it in simpler way?

```
dict= { "philips": "bulb", "cisca": "led"}

print(dict.values()
```

I want to access "philips " from "bulb"

Thankyou

Comment: You can maintain a different map {value:key}, or iterate every time over the values to extract the key

Answer (score 2):

```
print([k for k,v in dict.items() if v=='bulb'])
```

please note that you can have multiple keys with the same value.

Answer (score 1):

Check this question: [Python: Best Way to Exchange Keys with Values in a Dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031851/python-best-way-to-exchange-keys-with-values-in-a-dictionary)

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1031860/2194843):

```
>>> a = {'philips': 'bulb', 'cisca': 'led'}
>>> res = dict(zip(a.values(), a.keys()))
>>> res["bulb"]
'philips'
```

Comment: And if you had multiple keys with the same value of 'bulb'?