# Reversing a dict with python

Tags: python

I need to write a function that's these reverses the input.

Write a function reverse(dct) that takes as input a dict and returns a new dict where the keys and values have been flipped.
You can assume the input dict has only string values.

What would be the code for this?

```
.>>> reverse({"boy": "ragazzo", "girl": "ragazza", "baby": "bambino"})

{'ragazzo': 'boy', 'ragazza': 'girl', 'bambino': 'baby'}


.>>> reverse({"boy": "niño", "girl": "niña", "baby": "bebe"})

{'niño': 'boy', 'niña': 'girl', 'bebe': 'baby'}

.>>> reverse({"boy": "garcon", "girl": "fille", "baby": "bébé"})

{'garcon': 'boy', 'fille': 'girl', 'bébé': 'baby'}
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1031878/12095613) on how to flip keys and values in a dictionary.

Comment: @foureyes9408 no, don't; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1087957/4799172) which is more idiomatic. There's nothing wrong with the top answer, but I don't see why they called `dict()` rather than use a dictionary comprehension that came with Python 3

Answer (score 1):

```
reverse_dict = {value: key for key, value in dict.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Map `reversed` to the dicts items:

```
def reverse(dct):
    return dict(map(reversed, dct.items()))
```

Answer (score 0):

It gonna be like:
(i use python 3.7)

```
def reverse(my_map):
    inv_map = {v: k for k, v in my_map.items()}
    return(inv_map)
```