# Alter dictionary to map values to length of value

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary, for-loop

I have the following dictionary:

```
dict = {12:'Apples', 13:'Bananas', 14:'Oranges', 15:'Cherries'}
```

I want to rewrite this dictionary so that the values of `dict` become the keys of the `new_dict`. Then the values of `new_dict` will be the length of each new value, as follows:

```
new_dict = {'Apples':6, 'Bananas':7, 'Oranges':7, 'Cherries':8}
```

I am able to swap the values using

```
new_dict{}
for key,value in dict.items():
  new_dict[key] = [value]
  print(new_dict[key])
  counts = len(new_dict[key])
```

But the len function here counts how many values are present, not how many characters *per* value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I exchange keys with values in a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031851/how-do-i-exchange-keys-with-values-in-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following using a dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {12:'Apples', 13:'Bananas', 14:'Oranges', 15:'Cherries'}

d_new = {v: len(v) for v in d.values()}
```

**Output:**

```
>>> d_new
{'Apples': 6, 'Bananas': 7, 'Oranges': 7, 'Cherries': 8}
```

Note you should not use `dict` as a variable name as you overwrite the builtin [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) class.

This is equivalent to the following for loop:

```
new_dict = {}
for v in d.values():
    new_dict[v] = len(v)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `dict` function by zipping the values and the lengths:

```
d = {12:'Apples', 13:'Bananas', 14:'Oranges', 15:'Cherries'}
d_new = dict(zip(d.values(), map(len, d.values())))
```

Results

```
{'Apples': 6, 'Bananas': 7, 'Oranges': 7, 'Cherries': 8}
```