# How to change key to value in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def allicate(a_dict):
    ans_dict = {}
    for key,item in a_dict.items():
        ans_dict[item] = [key]
    return ans_dict


my_dict = {
"name.txt":"Ram",
"teach.txt":"Shyam",
"cod.txt":"Ram"}

print(allicate(my_dict))
```

It should print

```
{"Ram":["name.txt","cod.txt"],
 "Shyam":["teach.txt"]}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I exchange keys with values in a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031851/how-do-i-exchange-keys-with-values-in-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def allicate(a_dict):
    ans_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for key,item in a_dict.items():
        ans_dict[item].append(key)
    return ans_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def allicate(a_dict):
    ans_dict = {}
    for key, value in a_dict.items():
        if value in ans_dict:
            ans_dict[value].append(key)
        else:
            ans_dict.update({value:[key]})
    return ans_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code. You should check if your dict contains the required key or not (I have added comments to the related parts in the code. Please see below).

**Code:**

```
def allicate(a_dict):
    ans_dict = {}
    for key, item in a_dict.items():
        if item in ans_dict:  # If key exists in your dict.
            ans_dict[item].append(key)  # Append the element to the list.
            continue  # Get next element.
        ans_dict[item] = [key]  # Create a new key if it doesn't exist in you dict.
    return ans_dict


my_dict = {"name.txt": "Ram", "teach.txt": "Shyam", "cod.txt": "Ram"}

print(allicate(my_dict))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
{'Ram': ['name.txt', 'cod.txt'], 'Shyam': ['teach.txt']}
```